# SdFat library Change output style of sd.ls(LS_R)

Tags: arduino-mega, communication, sd-card

I'm using the [SdFat Library's](https://github.com/greiman/SdFat) `sd.ls(LS_R)` function to give me a serial output stream of all files on an SD card. My issue is that I would like to have it use a different character than '\n' at the end of each line as I'm using it as a termchar for my overall comms protocol. How can I get it to print a `:` or (another symbol that doesn't appear in file names) instead of a `\ln`

Answer (score 1):

I am currently trying to have fun Modding my own sd.ls().

Worst way, modifying the library:

Go into FatFilePrint.cpp

(Suggestion: Create yourself a new 'flag' like LS_COMMA)

Find the line

```
void FatFile::ls(print_t* pr, uint8_t flags, uint8_t indent) { ...
```

add your flag

```
if (flag & !LS_COMMA) {
   pr-->write(':');
} else {
    //original library set of 
    // pr->write(stuff);
}
```

## --> SuperClass version # (prefered )

this will override the original ls() method by creating a new Class inheriting from the original one.

rather then invoking it from "volume", 
    sd.ls( **your params**);

invoke it from a directory file instead.

```
superFatFile rootDir;
rootDir.open("/");
rootDir.ls( __your_params__);
```

Place this superClass declaration in your .h
don't hesitate to remove any of the "flags" related code if YOUR requirement never calls for them.

```
class superFatFile : public FatFile {
    public:
    void ls(print_t* pr, uint8_t flags /* = 0 */, uint8_t indent /* = 0 */){
        superFile file;
        rewind();
        while (file.openNext(this, O_READ)) {
            if (!file.isHidden() || (flags & LS_A)) {
                // adds 'spaces' indent for dir level
                for (uint8_t i = 0; i < indent; i++) {
                    pr->write(' ');
                }

                if (flags & LS_DATE) {
                    file.printModifyDateTime(pr);
                    pr->write(' ');
                }

                if (flags & LS_SIZE) {
                    file.printFileSize(pr);
                    pr->write(' ');
                }

                // prints filename
                if (!file.isDir()) {    
                    file.printName(pr);
                    pr->write('\r');
                    pr->write('\n');    // HERE IS YOUR SEPARATOR CARACTERS !!!
                }

                // execute recursivly if LS_R flag was set
                if ((flags & LS_R) && file.isDir()) file.ls(pr, flags, indent + 2);

            }

        }
        file.close();
    } // end of new LS method
}; // end of superClass
```

Comment: Nice,

I ended up changing my termchar